# AttributeError: module 'pypandoc' has no attribute 'convert'

Tags: pyspark, python-poetry, pypandoc

I am trying to switch a python project over to poetry & pyproject.toml. Previously, we were using requirements.txt.

When I try to install `pyspark 2.4.8` with poetry, however, I hit this error:

```
File "<string>", line 156, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'pypandoc' has no attribute 'convert'
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed
```

Has anyone run into this? Do you know why this is an issue with poetry but not with `requirements.txt`?

Comment: Share your requirements.txt file and toml file

Answer (score 6):

I solved this problem with:

`pip install pypandoc==1.5`

Comment: `pip install 'pypandoc<1.8'` was sufficient for me given the answer of @sango

Answer (score 2):

it seems you need to downgrade it since 'convert' was removed in the 1.8 version.
https://github.com/man-group/pytest-plugins/issues/87

Answer (score 0):

Change the call from `pypandoc.convert('README.md', 'rst')` to `pypandoc.convert_file('README.md', 'rst')`